# Event and Data Triggers can be combined?

Tags: wpf, triggers, datatrigger, eventtrigger, multidatatrigger

Is it possible to declare a `MultiTrigger` with an `Event` and a `DataTrigger`?

I have a scenario to start a `Storyboard` which is given in the `Event Trigger` when a bool Property of Control is set to `True`.

That why i need to make these two as a `MultiTrigger`. I know that there is no direct way to do it, but am looking for any workaround..

Any idea on this?

Comment: I have an idea... why don't you just try it? It will take you maybe one minute at most to find out.

Comment: @Genius: Great idea.. :P Without trying no one raise query right..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an workaround for this..

Creating a property in the Custom control and that to be targeted and changed in the Storyboard.

The property which is targeted previously was bound with this new Property as `MultiBuinding` and have converter for that. So there i can get both the values, with that i can return the value which required for the base property.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [`MultiTrigger` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.multitrigger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN, which [*should* have been your first place to search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), you can see an example that clearly shows that a `MultiTrigger` does *not* contain `Trigger`s... it contains `Condition` and `Setter` elements. From the linked page on MSDN:

```
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="HasItems" Value="false" />
        <Condition Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120"/>
</MultiTrigger>
```

So no, you cannot combine `Trigger`s *inside* a `MultiTrigger`.

Please note that searching the internet with the words from your title 'Combine Event and Data Triggers' also displayed several posts with answers. As a member of this site, you are expected to '[Search and Research](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)' *before* you ask a question to avoid simple and duplicate questions from being posted. Please do so in future.

Comment: Thanks, I know some basic knowledge how to place questions here. Though this was mentioned in several post, I avent come up with the solution what i required. If i post it here means, i can get any workaround for my exact requirement.

Comment: I am googling the exact same thing. Without this question I would not have been brought to SO.  This text above does not help me nor endear me to SO. May I respectfully suggest that a person's abilities (search as well as coding) be considered. It is nice to know that it cannot be done but what are the alternatives? One normally would make these kinds of suggestions to assist both the questioner and the completeness of SO.